# VBNET Cancel a Backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am new to programming and decided to start with VB.NET. I am writing a simple program for myself that list all files from a string. Everything is doing well except for the BackgroundWorker, I want to include a cancel capability just in case I want to change my search criteria I wont have to close my application then start over again. However I am having an issue despite checking the internet for a solution. None of them work on my case. Here is a part of my code. Also of you could suggest a better approach I would appreciate it.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        MsgBox("Already Running...")
    Else
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    Else
        MsgBox("Already Terminated...")
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Lister(ByVal Root As String)
    Try
        For Each file In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Root, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly)
            setLabelTxt(file, label1)
        Next

        For Each folder In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(Root)
            Lister(folder)
        Next
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Do
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            Lister("C:\")
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        MsgBox("Cancelled")
    Else
        MsgBox("Completed")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub setLabelTxt(ByVal text As String, ByVal lbl As Label)
    If lbl.InvokeRequired Then
        lbl.Invoke(New setLabelTxtInvoker(AddressOf setLabelTxt), text, lbl)
    Else
        lbl.Text = text
    End If
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub setLabelTxtInvoker(ByVal text As String, ByVal lbl As Label)
```

Comment: You check for `CancellationPending` *once* and then proceed with the lengthy operation. You never check for `CancellationPending` again from that operation. A better approach altogether would be get rid of the workers, [make `Lister` `async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/) and have it accept a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Ohh, Thank you for your response, I'll try your suggestions then reply with my outcome. Thanks again

Comment: Two things: (1) You don't need the `Do...Loop` and `Exit Do` parts, and (2) Just add a check for `CancellationPending` **inside** the `For...Next` loops and call `Exit Sub` to stop the search.

Comment: (3) What use is it to flash a result in a Label?  You'll only see the **last** result...consider appending to the Label, or possibly creating a List(Of String) with the results and doing something with that.